# Translating data.table to dplyr: Is there something equivalent to setting the keys of a data table before merge on dplyr?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I'm used to working on data table, but moving to use more dplyr. On data.table, if you set the keys of your your data before merging two data tables, the merge is much faster. Is there something equivalent to that in joining on dplyr?

```
library(tidyverse)

band_members_dt <- data.table::as.data.table(band_members)
band_instruments_dt <- data.table::as.data.table(band_instruments)

system.time({
  data.table::setkey(band_members_dt, name)
  data.table::setkey(band_instruments_dt, name)
  dt_merge <- merge(band_members_dt, band_instruments_dt, 
                    by = data.table::key(band_members_dt), all.x = T)
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.004   0.000   0.003 

system.time({
  tbl_join <- band_members %>% 
    left_join(band_instruments)
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.05    0.00    0.05
```

Obviously for a small data set the difference is not much, but I'm working with data in the order of millions of rows, and the difference can get pretty big, especially if you are making multiple merges of smaller data tables into a big one. And I would work on data.table, except the rest of the team prefers dplyr, plus is planning on using Spark too.

Comment: I'm not aware of a `dplyr` equivalent to `setkey`. Typically, if speed is a concern, that would be an argument for switching to `data.table`, not away from it.

Comment: No. There's an open issue on the dplyr GitHub suggesting a `set_key` feature: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1792

Comment: evidence supporting @Mako212 https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/